# About Reverse proxy

Tags: reverse-proxy

I am new in server and networking

Few weeks ago I have try to make reverse proxy and there is working successfully but after I try out, there appear that server from my system is only read the IP of the reverse proxy

The example is I have reverse proxy in 123.123.123.123

When I open that IP, there is directly pointing to my site. In my site, there is appear that my visiting is come from 123.123.123.123 not my original IP

Is there are any method I miss in making this reverse proxy??

Answer (score 3):

This is completely normal. If your web service understands [X-Forwarded-For](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) headers or the [proxy protocol](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/haproxy/proxy-protocol/) these are two ways to retain the traffic origin through a reverse proxy.

Comment: Hi

which web service should understands x forwarded for headers or proxy protocol?? the reverse proxy server or backend??

Comment: The reverse proxy must be capable of adding the header or using the protocol, and the backend server must be able to understand whichever you’re using. For HTTP, the header is the simple solution and most reverse proxies and regular web servers should be able to set and read them respectively.